# How can I redirect my command output using a shared memory segment?

Tags: c

I'm trying to redirect my command using my shared memory.

To summarize: my program runs as follows: I run ./server waiting for information, written when I run ./client. Client sends the information via a named pipe (mkfifo) to the server. That information is: the type of command to execute, the data and the name of the shared memory segment (create in the client with shm_open ftruncate shm_unlink and finally char * addr = mmap () ....). If I launched my program without redirecting the standard output, the result of the command would be displayed in the terminal where the server was executed ... Nevertheless, I would like it to appear in the client!
Here is the piece of code in the server :

```
    if ((fd = shm_open(req->shm_name, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1) {
    perror("shm_open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char *dir = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
  int tube[2];
  if (pipe(tube) == -1) {
    perror("tube");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  switch (fork()) {
  case -1:
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  case 0:
    getcwd(dir, 256);
    strcat(dir, "/info_proc");
    char *pid = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(pid, "%d", req->data);
    if (close(tube[0]) == -1) {
      perror("close");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

      if (dup2(tube[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      /*if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }*/

      execl(dir, "info_proc", pid, NULL);
      perror("execl");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default:
      wait(NULL);
      /*if (dup2(fd, tube[0]) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }*/

      if (close(tube[1]) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      char *received = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
      while (read(tube[0], &received, sizeof(received)));
      //addr = received;

      /*fd = tube[0];
      if (read(tube[0], &addr, BUFFER_SIZE) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }*/

      break;
  }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: To begin with, if you want the server to open the shared memory segment by the name provided by the client, then the client must not `shm_unlink()` it before the server does so.  Disassociating the name from the segment is the express purpose of `shm_unlink()`.  (That any shared memory segment not associated with a name is removed when no process has it open any longer is a secondary effect, albeit an important one.)

Comment: Thank you for this information! Currently, the shm_unlink is commented in the client ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you should be able to map a *stream* to your shared memory segment via `fmemopen()`, you need a *file descriptor* to perform redirection via `dup2()` or its siblings.  You can extract a file descriptor for most streams via the `fileno()` function, but I find that that does not work with memory streams, presumably because such streams do not correspond to an underlying open file description in the kernel.

Therefore, if you want to capture the standard output (and maybe standard error?) of the executed command, then you'll need to redirect it to a pipe, and have another process service the other end of the pipe to copy the data to the shared memory segment.

Here's an approach that makes sense to me:

- the client creates the shared memory segment, then
- the client opens the fifo and writes its request to it
- the server reads the request and forks a child process to handle it
- the child opens the designated shared memory segment and unlinks it
- the child creates a pipe, then
- the child forks its own child (the grandchild) in which to run the client's command
- the grandchild redirects its standard output to the write end of the pipe
- the child reads the output from the pipe and writes it to the shared memory segment until it reaches the end

Notes:

- Although you cannot use `fmemopen()` to redirect *directly* to the shared memory segment, it can still help you
- You can use `fstat()` to get the size of the shared memory segment, which the server will need to know
- creating and managing the grandchild might be simplified by using `popen()` instead of piping, forking, etc.
- You need a way to tell the client that the output is ready, and, incidentally, to synchronize access to the shared memory segment.  For example, the client might create a named semaphore for the server to use for the purpose.